# AWS EC2 requests to server result in ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT from anywhere but localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, server, actix-web

I have created an EC2 instance and started a server there. The server is up and running as a service with `systemd`. However, accesing the server anywhere but on localhost results in a time out.

When running `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`:
[netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrTQ6.png)

The server is written in rust with Actix and I bind it to ip `0.0.0.0`:

```
.bind(format!("0.0.0.0:{}",port))?
```

When I am on the EC2 instance through ssh, sending a GET request to localhost like so `curl "localhost:8080/games"` gives back a response as if everything works fine.

I also made sure that the security group assigned to the EC2 instance accepts TCP requests from anywhere on port 8080.
[inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP6J1.png)

To note, on this EC2 instance I also run nginx which serves a static single page application on the default HTTP port 80 which works just fine.

What am I missing? I have no clue what to do anymore.

I have tried:

- restarting the EC2 instance
- changing nginx configuration
- restarting the server service
- changing inbound rules on the security group